# How to setup phabricator with amazon rds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, phabricator

I want to setup a aws vm with phabricator. I need its db to be reliable, secure and automatically backed up. It seems amazon rds gives all of that.

I'd like to know whether it is possible to make phabricator use amazon RDS as db. How do I make sure data and backup are secure?

Comment: Doing a quick check over the software it looks like using RDS should work just fine. RDS does not work in cases where you would need access to the filesystem of the database server (LOAD DATA INFILE). Most applications wont run into problems like that.

Comment: RDS should work fine, but we don't have specific recommendations for installing on a particular OS, environment, or configuration. For discussion, see https://secure.phabricator.com/T4200

Comment: So what type of EC2 instance did you end up with, and did u start using RDS, and how about the pricing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. I'm using Phabricator with RDS right now. There are 1 or 2 things you need to snapshot depending on your usage pattern. (Mainly the repository hosting.)

Obviously you need RDS snapshot for back up. However that's done automatically by RDS. I provisioned another disk to host the Repository. I snapshot that as well.